# Can I have two different UV unwrappings of the same object?

Tags: uv

Basically, I have two textures, one of which is mostly transparent. I want to combine them, so that they're one on top of the other.

The problem is that one is bigger than the other, so I would need two different UV unwrappings of the same object, one with a bigger scale than the other.

Is it possible to do so or should I combine the textures in an external program?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Combining textures is not a bad idea either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

In the mesh panel, under *UV Maps*, press the "+" button. This will create a new UV map with the same coordinates as the existing one.

For [Cycles](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles), in the node editor, select *Input* -> *UV Map* to use different UV maps for different shader parts.

In [Blender Internal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render), you can select which UV map to use in the texture panels.

Comment: That was quick! And it worked perfectly, I'll accept the answer as soon as I'm allowed to!

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**

Just go to the *object data* panel of the *properties* view (where you go to modify vertex groups) and click the little "+" under  the *UV maps* rollout to add a UV map.  Then when you go to UV unwrap a model just select the UV map you want to modify.