# How to assign which UV map when multiple are available to use in 2.8+?

Tags: mesh, materials, uv

I read this question about having two different UV mappings on a model.
[Can I have two different UV unwrappings of the same object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23093/can-i-have-two-different-uv-unwrappings-of-the-same-object)

I have two versions of UV map for a mesh and I want to pick which UV gets used on which material in 2.8 but I do not see where to do that. How can this be done in 2.8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using the [*UV Map*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/uv_map.html) node (*Input > UV Map*), it allows you to select one of the UV maps associated with the object. The *Texture Coordinate* node always uses the active UV map.

[image: Nodes]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer also led me to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/uv/layout_management.html#multiple-uv-maps for being able to set/hide which UV map is the active one.